# Merge encrypted pdf file programmatically exception

Tags: java, android, pdf, itext, itext7

I have been using the following code to merge encrypted pdf files programmatically.

```java
public void mergeMyFiles(String filesToBeMerged[], String mergedFileLocation, String password) {
    try {
        int pageOffset = 0;
        ArrayList masterBookMarkList = new ArrayList();

        int fileIndex = 0;
        String outFile = mergedFileLocation;
        Document document = null;
        PdfCopy writer = null;
        PdfReader reader = null;
        PdfReader.unethicalreading = true;
        for (fileIndex = 0; fileIndex < filesToBeMerged.length; fileIndex++) {
            /**
             * Create a reader for the file that we are reading
             */
            reader = new PdfReader(filesToBeMerged[fileIndex], password.getBytes());
            /**
             * Replace all the local named links with the actual destinations.
             */
            reader.consolidateNamedDestinations();

            /**
             * Retrieve the total number of pages for this document
             */
            int totalPages = reader.getNumberOfPages();

            /**
             * Get the list of bookmarks for the current document
             * If the bookmarks are not empty, store the bookmarks
             * into a master list
             */
            List bookmarks = SimpleBookmark.getBookmark(reader);
            if (bookmarks != null) {
                if (pageOffset != 0)
                    SimpleBookmark.shiftPageNumbers(bookmarks, pageOffset,
                        null);
                masterBookMarkList.addAll(bookmarks);
                System.out.println("Bookmarks found and storing...");
            } else {
                System.out.println("No bookmarks in this file...");
            }
            pageOffset += totalPages;

            /**
             * Merging the files to the first file.
             * If we are passing file1, file2 and file3,
             * we will merge file2 and file3 to file1.
             */
            if (fileIndex == 0) {
                /**
                 * Create the document object from the reader
                 */
                document = new Document(reader.getPageSizeWithRotation(1));

                /**
                 * Create a pdf write that listens to this document.
                 * Any changes to this document will be written the file
                 *
                 * outFile is a location where the final merged document
                 * will be written to.
                 */

                System.out.println("Creating an empty PDF...");
                writer = new PdfCopy(document, new FileOutputStream(outFile));
                /**
                 * Open this document
                 */
                document.open();
            }
            /**
             * Add the conent of the file into this document (writer).
             * Loop through multiple Pages
             */
            System.out.println("Merging File: " + filesToBeMerged[fileIndex]);
            PdfImportedPage page;
            for (int currentPage = 1; currentPage <= totalPages; currentPage++) {
                page = writer.getImportedPage(reader, currentPage);
                writer.addPage(page);
            }

            /**
             * This will get the documents acroform.
             * This will return null if no acroform is part of the document.
             *
             * Acroforms are PDFs that have been turned into fillable forms.
             */
            System.out.println("Checking for Acroforms");
            PRAcroForm form = reader.getAcroForm();
            if (form != null) {
                //writer.copyAcroForm(reader);
                writer.addDocument(reader);
                System.out.println("Acroforms found and copied");
            } else
                System.out.println("Acroforms not found for this file");

            System.out.println();
        }
        /**
         * After looping through all the files, add the master bookmarklist.
         * If individual PDF documents had separate bookmarks, master bookmark
         * list will contain a combination of all those bookmarks in the
         * merged document.
         */
        if (!masterBookMarkList.isEmpty()) {
            writer.setOutlines(masterBookMarkList);
            System.out.println("All bookmarks combined and added");

        } else {
            System.out.println("No bookmarks to add in the new file");

        }

        /**
         * Finally Close the main document, which will trigger the pdfcopy
         * to write back to the filesystem.
         */
        document.close();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

I started getting this error recently upon trying to create the pdfReader at this line of code:

```java
reader = new PdfReader(filesToBeMerged[fileIndex], password.getBytes());
```

> com.itextpdf.text.exceptions.InvalidPdfException: Unknown encryption type R = 6
> at com.itextpdf.text.pdf.PdfReader.readPdf(PdfReader.java:738)
> at com.itextpdf.text.pdf.PdfReader.(PdfReader.java:181)
> at com.itextpdf.text.pdf.PdfReader.(PdfReader.java:219)
> at com.itextpdf.text.pdf.PdfReader.(PdfReader.java:207)
> at com.project.mainPageShop.mergeMyFiles(mainPageShop.java:4368)
> at com.project.mainPageShop$DownloadFileAsync.onPostExecute(mainPageShop.java:11757)
> at com.project.mainPageShop$DownloadFileAsync.onPostExecute(mainPageShop.java:11628)
> at android.os.AsyncTask.finish(AsyncTask.java:755)
> at android.os.AsyncTask.access$900(AsyncTask.java:192)
> at android.os.AsyncTask$InternalHandler.handleMessage(AsyncTask.java:772)
> at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:107)
> at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:237)
> at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7814)
> at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
> at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:493)
> at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1068)

Kindly note that the password is correct, and same file which use to work using this code, is now raising this exception.

**UPDATE:**

I have used the following code using **com.itextpdf:itext7-core:7.0.2**

```java
public void mergePDFFiles(String FILE1, String FILE2, String mergedFileLocation, String password) {
    try {
        PdfReader pdf1 = new PdfReader(FILE1);
        pdf1.setUnethicalReading(true);
        PdfReader pdf2 = new PdfReader(FILE2);
        pdf2.setUnethicalReading(true);
        PdfDocument pdfDocument = new PdfDocument(pdf1, new PdfWriter(mergedFileLocation));
        PdfDocument pdfDocument2 = new PdfDocument(pdf2);

        PdfMerger merger = new PdfMerger(pdfDocument);
        merger.merge(pdfDocument2, 1, pdfDocument2.getNumberOfPages());

        pdfDocument2.close();
        pdfDocument.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

This is the logcat Result:

> FATAL EXCEPTION: main
> Process: com.project, PID: 7665
> com.itextpdf.kernel.PdfException: Unknown encryption type R == 6.
> at com.itextpdf.kernel.pdf.PdfEncryption.readAndSetCryptoModeForStdHandler(PdfEncryption.java:508)
> at com.itextpdf.kernel.pdf.PdfEncryption.(PdfEncryption.java:181)
> at com.itextpdf.kernel.pdf.PdfReader.readDecryptObj(PdfReader.java:1061)
> at com.itextpdf.kernel.pdf.PdfReader.readPdf(PdfReader.java:531)
> at com.itextpdf.kernel.pdf.PdfDocument.open(PdfDocument.java:1585)
> at com.itextpdf.kernel.pdf.PdfDocument.(PdfDocument.java:281)
> at com.itextpdf.kernel.pdf.PdfDocument.(PdfDocument.java:249)
> at com.project.mainPageShop.mergePDFFiles(mainPageShop.java:4353)
> at com.neelwafurat.iKitabForAndroid.mainPageShop$DownloadFileAsync.onPostExecute(mainPageShop.java:11788)
> at com.project.mainPageShop$DownloadFileAsync.onPostExecute(mainPageShop.java:11659)
> at android.os.AsyncTask.finish(AsyncTask.java:755)
> at android.os.AsyncTask.access$900(AsyncTask.java:192)
> at android.os.AsyncTask$InternalHandler.handleMessage(AsyncTask.java:772)
> at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:107)
> at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:237)
> at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7814)
> at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
> at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:493)
> at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1068)

The error is occurring at the following line:

```java
PdfDocument pdfDocument = new PdfDocument(pdf1, new PdfWriter(mergedFileLocation));
```

Find below links for sample encrypted pdf files used with password: 123456

https://smallpdf.com/shared#st=8921059d-6615-4264-a3f6-c76d476dc168&fn=test+1.pdf&ct=1602755420749&tl=share-document&rf=link

https://smallpdf.com/shared#st=7d3c11c7-b34d-4399-bc03-c66b7be788d0&fn=test+2.pdf&ct=1602755505331&tl=share-document&rf=link

Comment: `encryption type R = 6` is newer than itext 5.x active development.

Comment: I have updated the iText to itextpdf-5.5.9.jar and distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-5.6.4-all.zip is there a newer version I can update to?

Comment: As I said, as far as I know itext 5.x does not support R=6. For quite a number of years there were only bug fixes and security fixes, no new features.

Comment: I tried iText 7, same error occurred, what can be done work with encrypted pdf files?

Comment: For iText 7 please share an example pdf. I'm sure that's something they'll want to support in iText 7.

Comment: I have updated the question with sample files: new code and the log result received

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Revision 6 of the standard security handler is not supported in iText 5 or iText 7.0.2. It was introduced in iText 7.1.0 in the context of PDF 2.0 support.

I have slightly tweaked your code sample to test. Note that you were not passing the password to the `PdfReader` instance.

Also note that the password you shared for the sample PDFs (`123456`) is the user password, not the owner password.

A *user password*, also called *open password*, is used to *open* a PDF document, i.e. to give access to the content. All other restrictions are handled by an *owner password*, also called *permissions password*, e.g. allowing/preventing a document being printed.

For your sample documents, both the open password and permissions password are set:

[image: PDF permissions]

If you have the owner password available, you should use it the process the PDF, i.e. pass it to the `PdfReader` instance. That allows you to avoid the `unethicalreading` setting.

Test code:

```java
public void mergePDFFiles(String FILE1, String FILE2, String mergedFileLocation, String password)
{
    try {
        PdfReader pdf1 = new PdfReader(FILE1,
            new ReaderProperties().setPassword(password.getBytes()));
        pdf1.setUnethicalReading(true);
        PdfReader pdf2 = new PdfReader(FILE2,
            new ReaderProperties().setPassword(password.getBytes()));
        pdf2.setUnethicalReading(true);
        PdfDocument pdfDocument = new PdfDocument(pdf1, new PdfWriter(mergedFileLocation));
        PdfDocument pdfDocument2 = new PdfDocument(pdf2);

        PdfMerger merger = new PdfMerger(pdfDocument);
        merger.merge(pdfDocument2, 1, pdfDocument2.getNumberOfPages());

        pdfDocument2.close();
        pdfDocument.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

iText 7.0.2 does not support revision 6, as you've noticed:

```
Exception in thread "main" com.itextpdf.kernel.PdfException: Unknown encryption type R == 6.
    at com.itextpdf.kernel.pdf.PdfEncryption.readAndSetCryptoModeForStdHandler(PdfEncryption.java:508)
    at com.itextpdf.kernel.pdf.PdfEncryption.<init>(PdfEncryption.java:181)
    at com.itextpdf.kernel.pdf.PdfReader.readDecryptObj(PdfReader.java:1061)
    at com.itextpdf.kernel.pdf.PdfReader.readPdf(PdfReader.java:531)
    at com.itextpdf.kernel.pdf.PdfDocument.open(PdfDocument.java:1585)
    at com.itextpdf.kernel.pdf.PdfDocument.<init>(PdfDocument.java:281)
    at com.itextpdf.kernel.pdf.PdfDocument.<init>(PdfDocument.java:249)
```

Starting from iText 7.1.0 up until the current release (7.1.13), your 2 sample files will merge correctly, resulting in a 4-page output file.

Comment: Would you also clarify the difference between owner password and user password, as I created these pdf files, and the only password I used to encrypt them was the one I gave.

Comment: I have added clarification regarding owner and user password in my answer.